# Is there a way to display a Unity game in half of the screen on a mobile app or to put Swift UI elements on top of a Unity game in an iOS app?

Tags: ios, reactjs, swift, unity-game-engine

I am currently looking for some way to display either a window with a Unity game or a fullscreen Unity game with swift UI elements added on top of it. Has anyone done this before or know if this is possible?

I haven't yet tried anything, currently just trying to pick out my tech stack for this project and see if its possible in any stack.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Unity has ViewController for rendering game scene.
You can get UnityAppController how call `unityFramework.appController()`.

UnityAppController can used as such as other ViewControllers.
It also work by using UIViewControllerRepresentable in SwiftUI case.

This technique called `Unity as a Library`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. That helps! Just found this tutorial based on looking that up which gives results along the lines of what I want so I think I'll be able to get everything to work with this. I'll link it here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DLkeGz5vCzk&ab_channel=SwiftKatCodeFactory

Comment: But I want to change the unity rootview failed.auto view = [[[self ufw] appController] rootView];
    view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 400);